# Create a insert/view/edit forms for an existing list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am a new to using sharepoint. I have a requirement of creating a form which can be used to insert, edit and view the data by multiple users. Currently I am maintaining all the details in excel sheet uploaded in the sharepoint. There are few other users who update the details, however, I am facing problems with excel sheet and thought of creating sharepoint forms.

I have gone through multiple websites to understand how to create the forms. However, I did not find a good starting guide anywhere. Can anyone help me with proper links to proceed further.

PS I am using SharePoint online (Plan2) version.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, you can export your excel into SharePoint and SharePoint will create a list for you.

The list which will be created by exporting excel will have same view like Excel.

Along with the list, the form will be automatically gets created.

Let me know if you are looking for same.

In order to exporting excel to SharePoint, you can read [article here.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-excel-data-to-sharepoint-custom-list/)

Comment: thanks aakash. It worked.. but, the form that got created is a basic one (fields listed in a vertical layout.). Is there a way to create a form that can be customized?

Comment: Depending on the type of site (Classic, Modern) you can use SharepointDesigner or Infopath to modify the forms (if that is enabled for your tenant) of if  you are on modern you can use PowerApps to make modifications.